# Cast Iron Sewage Vent Pipe Condensation Freezing Problem

Tags: water, condensation, winter, cast-iron

this winter I noticed condensation freezing on my sewage vent pipe. I know I'll need to remediate the area after the fix. Any recommendations or experience with this type of problem? For context if needed, northern US - 1920's house.

Thank you!

[image: Frozen Condensation]

Comment: Is this causing you any specific issues? When the condensation melts, it'll flow to the ground outside, or to the drain inside... Also "recommendations or experience with `x`" is a rather broad question. You might try asking _if_ it's an issue to be concerned about, then if it is, a new question on how to remediate the situation.

Comment: FreeMan - It's causing issues with my ceiling, freezing and melting is trapping the water in the house. The cast iron pipe runs through the house down to the basement, there isn't anything outside except the bit that is exposed on the roof.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the insulation around it, which looks all sorts of screwed up and not properly cut around it to lay properly, and then insulate around the pipe itself up to roof level. To get frost forming there, you likely have an air leak from inside the house you should fix while fixing the insulation. Frost inside the pipe is expected. Frost outside the pipe means there's moist air that's warm enough to have water freeze out on the cold metal pipe.

You could choose to cut the cast iron near the ceiling level and replace the upper part with PVC, but there's really no need to unless it's actually plugging with frost to the point that it won't vent properly. In that case it's typical to also increase the diameter of the section going through the roof, as well as insulating the outside of the pipe in the attic space. That level of fuss is generally only required in very cold climates.

Comment: The attic has gable vents/passive venting and is a "cold attic". My thought was the pipe is warm due to hot water or just warm house, then the cold attic air hits it creating the condensation. Noted on the cleanup of insulation and pipe wrap!

Comment: A vented attic (without air leaks) should not have moisture that will condense on the outside of the pipe, so my suspicion of air leaks from the comparatively warm/humid inside....